# Fernet InvalidToken Error during Password Decryption in Python

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, arguments, argparse

I'm encountering a `cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken` error while trying to decrypt passwords in my Python Password Manager. The issue occurs during retrieval. I'm using Fernet for encryption/decryption.

Here is my code:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import argparse
import os
import secrets
import string

class PasswordManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.master_key = None

    def set_master_password(self, master_password):
        self.master_key = Fernet(Fernet.generate_key())
        self.master_password = master_password.encode()

    def encrypt_password(self, password):
        return self.master_key.encrypt(password.encode())

    def decrypt_password(self, encrypted_password):
        return self.master_key.decrypt(encrypted_password).decode()

    def generate_password(self, length=12):
        characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
        if length < 8:
            raise ValueError("Password length must be at least 8 characters.")
        return ''.join(secrets.choice(characters) for _ in range(length))

    def store_password(self, service, password):
        encrypted_password = self.encrypt_password(password)
        with open('passwords.txt', 'a') as file:
            file.write(f"{service}: {encrypted_password}\n")

    def retrieve_password(self, service):
        with open('passwords.txt', 'r') as file:
            for line in file:
                entry = line.split(': ')
                if entry[0] == service:
                    encrypted_password = entry[1].encode()
                    return self.decrypt_password(encrypted_password)
            return None

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Password Manager")
    parser.add_argument('--action', choices=['store', 'retrieve', 'generate'], help='Operation to perform', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--master-password', help='Master password')
    parser.add_argument('--service', help='Service name')
    parser.add_argument('--password', help='Password')
    parser.add_argument('--length', type=int, default=12, help='Length of generated password')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    password_manager = PasswordManager()

    if args.action == 'store':
        if not args.master_password or not args.service or not args.password:
            print("Please provide master password, service, and password to store.")
        else:
            password_manager.set_master_password(args.master_password)
            password_manager.store_password(args.service, args.password)
            print("Password stored successfully.")

    elif args.action == 'retrieve':
        if not args.master_password or not args.service:
            print("Please provide master password and service to retrieve password.")
        else:
            password_manager.set_master_password(args.master_password)
            password = password_manager.retrieve_password(args.service)
            if password:
                print(f"Retrieved password for {args.service}: {password}")
            else:
                print(f"No password found for {args.service}.")

    elif args.action == 'generate':
        if not args.master_password:
            print("Please provide master password to generate a password.")
        else:
            password_manager.set_master_password(args.master_password)
            generated_password = password_manager.generate_password(args.length)
            print(f"Generated Password: {generated_password}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is actual error while receiving passwords:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/valan/Desktop/PasswordManager/passmanager_jsv/passwd_manager.py", line 80, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/valan/Desktop/PasswordManager/passmanager_jsv/passwd_manager.py", line 65, in main
    password = password_manager.retrieve_password(args.service)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/valan/Desktop/PasswordManager/passmanager_jsv/passwd_manager.py", line 38, in retrieve_password
    return self.decrypt_password(encrypted_password)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/valan/Desktop/PasswordManager/passmanager_jsv/passwd_manager.py", line 19, in decrypt_password
    return self.master_key.decrypt(encrypted_password).decode()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 85, in decrypt
    timestamp, data = Fernet._get_unverified_token_data(token)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 121, in _get_unverified_token_data
    raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
```

Comment: All of this aside, you're aware that _encrypted_ passwords are a terrible idea? Stored passwords should use a cryptographic hash, not encryption

Comment: Thank you for your insight and suggestion. I'm still learning about hash functions and their use in password security. If possible, could you provide some resources or guidance on how to correctly implement hash functions for storing passwords? I'm eager to improve my understanding and follow the best practices in password security. Any information or advice you can share would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The base principle is pretty simple. Encryption can be reversed, so you can go `string --> jumble --> string`. With a **cryptographic** hash you cannot reverse it. `string --> jumble -/-> string`. See [OWASP](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html) for a starter. Emphasis on _cryptographic_ - the `hash()` function in `python`, for example, is **not** a cryptographic hash